# Currently trying to sort an array using bubble sort and then getting the average but the average that returns is wrong.

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

```
else if (order == "average") {
    int average = 0;
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_TEAMS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NO_TEAMS - 1; j++)
        {
            if (ptr[yearIndex].teams[j].fum < ptr[yearIndex].teams[j + 1].fum) {
                temp = ptr[yearIndex].teams[i].fum;
                ptr[yearIndex].teams[j].fum = ptr[yearIndex].teams[j + 1].fum;
                ptr[yearIndex].teams[j + 1].lost = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_TEAMS; i++) {
        average = average + ptr[yearIndex].teams[i].fum;
    }
```

For this code, the average returns 26. However, if I eliminate the bubble sort code, then the average returns 20 (which is the correct average). How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't temp = ptr[yearIndex].teams[i].fum; be temp = ptr[yearIndex].teams[j].fum; //with j instead of i

Comment: Why? You don't need to sort to compute the average. I hope this is homework, otherwise you shouldn't be using bubble-sort at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you were not swapping the items correctly. 
The problem is in these three lines:

```
temp = ptr[yearIndex].teams[i].fum;
ptr[yearIndex].teams[j].fum = ptr[yearIndex].teams[j + 1].fum;
ptr[yearIndex].teams[j + 1].lost = temp
```

Change the first line to index by`j`, not `i`

```
temp = ptr[yearIndex].teams[j].fum;
```